# Does firebase realtime database unity package supports Universal Windows platform build?

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase realtime database, to send my score to server. It worked like charm for Android and iOS. However when i created build for universal windows platform, its not allowing me to crate build. So i removed firebase from my project and created build. Apart from score management, everything worked fine. So i am just surprised, does firebase supports universal windows platform build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/start?hl=en#configuring_the_sdk_for_the_unity_editor

You can use firebase realtime database in unity editor.

So it might be possible.

Comment: hi Saki, Thanks for your reply, However we are done it for unity editor. My query is about Universal Windows platform build. A build that would run on Desktops and Surface tablets. Does firebase supports UWP

Comment: Officially, Firebase dont supports UWP